# Swift UI Delegate methods not being working

Tags: swift, debugging, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to have my inputs inside of my UITextField show up in the debugger console, when I am typing in the created TextField however the Delegate Methods don't seem to be responding. I am expecting to see my print statement that are seen below for my UIdelegate methods, like when I first started typing, while I type, and when I press the 'return key'. All delegate methods do not seem to be activated, and I am not sure how to make my Textfield link to the delegate method directly. In addition, I have another UITextField (Not shown here), would I have to 'addTarget' to differentiate between the two?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {    

 let createUserName: UITextField = {
    var myTextField = UITextField ()
    myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myTextField.placeholder = "Username" //set placeholder text
    myTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14) // set font size of text field
    myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 //set width
    myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor//set background color to a ui color
    myTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = myTextField.frame.height/2
    myTextField.autocorrectionType = .no // disable autocorrect when typing for .no, enable with .yes
    myTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false// masked text
    myTextField.keyboardType = .default //keyboard style is set to default
    myTextField.returnKeyType = .default //retuen key text changed to "Done" instead of return
    myTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    myTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    return myTextField
}()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 createUserName.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(createUserName)
    setupUserName()
}

//UITextField Delegate methods

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("textfield should begin editting")
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
print("text field edit")
}


//see string that is typed in debugger for use to validate password and crossreference username
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

if let textFieldString = textField.text, let swtRange = Range(range, in: textFieldString) {

let fullString = textFieldString.replacingCharacters(in: swtRange, with: string)

print("FullString: \(fullString)")
}

return true
}

//dismiss keyboard when return button is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("text field return")
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your viewController should inherit from UITextFieldDelegate

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { 
 // your code
}
```

Also in your ViewDidLoad, move your createUsername.delegate = self to last line.

Comment: @keshurrai I added in the class line in my problem statement above so you can see everything. Putting the createUsername.delegate = self in the last line of the ViewDidLoad did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @keshurrai I realized I had one of my } closure not containing the delegate methods in my class so now it works

Answer (score 1):

That string:

```
myTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
```

tell us that your VC don't directly conform protocol UITextFieldDelegate...

If you conformed swift doesn't add as? cast ...

Comment: are you saying to take myTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate out?

Comment: I realized I had one of my } closure not containing the delegate methods in my class so now it works

Comment: congratulation! @bain